# Best possible chance to succeed with free choice of how many dice to roll for 4 players

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Each of the 4 players can roll however many d10's as they like. Howerver, for any single player ,if any of their rolls come up as the same number, their total is treated as a zero. 
You are shooting for a total of 65 or more between everyone results
How many dice should the survivors roll for the best chance of success?
I had an idea of going for averages. An average roll of a d10 is 5.5. SO each survivor should roll 3 dice. However, this only gives about a 70 percent chance for each to succeed because (10*9*8/1000) I believe. Is this really the best chance to get over a 65 on the rolls? Or is there a better chance if one person were to roll 4 dice etc.?

Comment: The largest possible total is 55, is not it?

Comment: Sorry., to clarify, its to get a total of 65 between all 4 players. So if each person got say a 20, the total would be 80.

Comment: Do the four people play as a team? Is there a winner?

Comment: yes they are a team. Everyone decides how many dice they wish to roll. from 0 to 10. They all win if their total is 65, they lose if it's lower. The main issue is if you roll too many dice, and get a double, that players score is now 0, rather than the total of their roll.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand enough details  of how the game is played.  What does "survivors" mean?  This would seem to imply that the players get more than one go.  Do they take it in turns to roll some number of 10-sided dice?  If this is the case, presumably when any of the numbers a player gets on a later turn repeats one of the numbers he got on a previous turn, his score is cancelled and he takes no further part.  Otherwise, the group could guarantee that they got to $65$ by throwing just a single die on each turn.

Comment: @lonzaleggieral If I understood correctly the next player can start rolling only after the previous person stops. Probably the decision to stop actually depends on the total count to that moment.

Comment: Ok I will clarify more. So All 4 players, ignore the word survivors, have  to choose before anyone rolls how many dice to roll. Everyone can talk to each other, but once you choose how many 10 sided dice to roll, that is locked in. Once everyone decides how many dice they wish to roll, you roll that many dice. So say every player decides to roll 4 dice. So say player 1 gets (10,9,1,2) his score is 22. If player 2 rolls (9,8,1,3,), their score is 21. So two players can roll the same number. However, if player 3 rolls (3,3,10,9) their score is 0, because they rolled two 3s.

Comment: Is the total score of the team the least score of all 4 players?

Comment: The total score is the score of all 4 players dice rolls combined. Let me give an example. Three players choose to roll 3 dice, and one player rolls 4. Player one rolls (10.2.5.) giving them a total of 17. Player 2 rolls (4,5,3,) giving them a total of 12. Player 3 rolls (9,6,6) meaning their total is 0 becdause they rolled two 6s. Finally, player 4 rolls (10,9,8,3) giving them 30. The total score would be 17+12+0+30=59. Since 59 is less than 65, the 4 players lose.

Answer (score 1):

According to my calculations, the four players' best chance of obtaining a total of $65$ or more is for all of them to roll four dice, even though the expected score of each, namely $11.088$, is slightly less than what it would be if they rolled only three dice, namely $11.88$.  The probability that their total score would be $65$ or more for various combinations of dice is given in the table below.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{Combination}&\mbox{probability}\\
\hline
3333&0.1621\\
\hline
3334&0.1761\\
\hline
3344&0.1815\\
\hline
3444&0.1948\\
\hline
4444&0.2096\\
\hline
\end{array}

The distribution of a player's score when he or she rolls $n$ dice is not difficult to compute. If the score is $\ S_n\ $, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{Pr}\left(S_n=0\right)&=&1-\frac{10!}{(10-n)!10^n}\ , \mbox{ and}\\ \mathrm{Pr}\left(S_n=k\right)&=&\frac{\left\vert\left\{D\subseteq\left\{1,2,\dots,10\right\}\left\vert\,\left| D\right\vert=n, \sum_\limits{j\in D}j =k\right.\right\}\right\vert}{10^n}\\
&&\mbox{for $k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\dots,\frac{n(21-n)}{2}$} .
\end{eqnarray}
These distributions are tabulated below for $\ n\ $ from $1$ to $10$.  These are the only values of $\ n $ that need to be considered, because throwing any more than $10$ dice is guaranteed to score zero.

If $\ \psi_n\ $ is the distribution of $\ S_n\ $, then the distribution of the players' total score when they throw $\ n_1, n_2,n_3,\ $ and $\ n_4\ $ dice, is the convolution $\ \psi_{n_1}*\psi_{n_2}*\psi_{n_3}*\psi_{n_4}\ $.  To establish that $\ 4,4,4,4\ $ is the best combination, I evaluated $\ \sum_\limits{j=65}^\infty\psi_{n_1}*\psi_{n_2}*\psi_{n_3}*\psi_{n_4}(j)\ $ for *all* quadruples of integers $\ n_1, n_2,n_3, n_4\ $ with $\ 1\le n_1\le n_2\le n_4\le 10\ $ and $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^4n_i \ge 7\ $, and found that this quantity was maximised by that combination.

### Distributions of $\ S_n\ $

### One die, $\ \psi_1\ $

Mean score = $5.5$
\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline
1-10\\
0.1\\
\hline
\end{array}

### Two dice, $\ \psi_2\ $

Mean score = $9.9$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&3,4,18,19&5,6,16,17&7,8,14,15&9,10,11,13&12\\
0.1&0.02&0.04&0.06&0.08&0.10\\
\hline
\end{array}

### Three, $\ \psi_3\ $

Mean score = $11.88$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&6,7,26,27&8,25&9,24&10,23\\
0.28&0.006&0.012&0.018&0.024\\
\hline
11,22&12,21&13,20&14,19&15,16,17,18\\
0.03&0.042&0.048&0.054&0.06\\
\hline
\end{array}

### Four, $\ \psi_4\ $

Mean score = $11.088$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&10,11,33,34&12,32&13,31&14,30&15,29\\
0.496&0.0024&0.0048&0.0072&0.012&0.0144\\
\hline
16,28&17,27&18,26&19,25&20,21,23,24&22\\
0.0216&0.024&0.0312&0.0336&0.0384&0.0432\\
\hline
\end{array}

### Five, $\ \psi_5\ $

Mean score = $8.316$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&15,16,39,40&17,38&18,37&19,36&20,35&21,34\\
0.6976&0.00012&0.0024&0.0036&0.006&0.0084&0.0108\\
\hline
22,33&23,32&24,31&25,30&26,29&27,28\\
0.0132&0.0168&0.0192&0.0216&0.0228&0.024\\
\hline
\end{array}

### Six, $\ \psi_6\ $

Mean score = $4.9896$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&21,22,44,45&23,43&24,42&25,41&26,40\\
0.8488&0.00072&0.00144&0.00216&0.0036&0.00432\\
\hline
27,39&28,38&29,37&30,36&31,32,33,35&34\\
0.00648&0.0072&0.00936&0.01008&0.01152 &0.01296\\
\hline
\end{array}

### Seven, $\ \psi_7\ $

Mean score=2.32848
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&28,29,48,49&30/47&31/46&32/45\\
0.93952&0.000504&0.001008&0.001512&0.002016\\
\hline
33/44&34/43&35/42&36/41&37,38,39,40\\
0.00252&0.003528&0.004032&0.004536&0.00504\\
\hline
\end{array}

### Eight, $\ \psi_8\ $

Mean score=0.798336
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&36,37,51,52&38,39,49,50&40,41,47,48&42,43,45,46&44\\
0.981856&0.0004032&0.0008064&0.0012096&0.0016128&0.002016\\
\hline
\hline
\end{array}

### Nine, $\ \psi_9\ $

Mean score=0.1796256
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&45-54\\
0.9963712&0.00036288\\
\hline
\end{array}.

### Ten, $\ \psi_{10}\ $

Mean score=0.0199584
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&55\\
0.99963712&0.00036288\\
\hline
\end{array}.